How much Heyting Arithmetic would be lost using only $\to$ and $\neg, \forall, \exists$ axioms for Intuitionistic Logic?
How much of Heyting Arithmetic is lost if one uses only implication and negation as propositional operators, and takes minimal implicational logic+axioms for intuitionistic negation and quantifiers?
I know that some definitions require conjunction, e.g. bounded existential quantification. I also know that Induction, which has a conjunction in the axiom, may be replaced with an equivalent version that does not use conjunction via currying.
Are there any notable losses aside from bounded existential quantification? Are some aspects of everyday arithmetic at stake as well? What about things like the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

How do you have $\exists$ well-defined semantically without disjunction in an intuitionistic system? The existence property, to my recollection, comes from the disjunction property.
To your more direct question, you don't "gain" or "lose" a Heyting algebra. There just are Heyting algebras that evaluate all and only the tautologies of whatever operational fragment as tautologies. Even a Boolean algebra is a Heyting algebra.

@JoshuaHarwood I misspoke. I meant Heyting Arithmetic. I’ll edit it.

@JoshuaHarwood would you refer me to a source that corroborates that the existential quantified needs disjunction semantically? I’ve never heard that before.

Sure. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/157772619.pdf Here, the reference points out that lacking the disjunction property, but having the existence property, is possible, but places it among intermediate (superintuitionistic) logics.

@JoshuaHarwood Is that to say that quantified minimal implicational logic doesn’t have an existence property?

I'm not sure what that all entails. I'm guessing it's a minimal logic with the operational fragment ${ \exists, \forall, \neg, \rightarrow }$. My impression would be that, since it's inferentially weaker than the corresponding intuitionistic fragment, its semantics that allows the existence property without the disjunction property will likewise be intermediate. Disallowing the EFQ (what minimal logic does) doesn't appear to impact that.
